# No known class method for selector "dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a `NSDatePicker` instance defined in my controller (subclass of `UIViewController`):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
```

I try to set the minimum date to be 60 seconds later than the current date time:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // No known class method for selector "dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow"
    self.datePicker.minimumDate = [NSData dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
}
```

But I got compiler error:

```
No known class method for selector "dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow"
```

I don't understand why?

Comment: Spelink misteak. NSData ≠ NSDate.

Answer (score 2):

Typo. You should use `NSDate` not `NSData` ;)

Comment: I need rest. Thank you.